# Contar quantidade de arquivos em pasta

Tags: php

Estou criando uma listagem de imagens contidas dentro de uma pasta, mas gostaria de contar a quantidade de arquivos dentro da pasta, como faço?
Segue abaixo o código estou utilizando:

```
<?php 

$pasta = 'imagens/';
$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($arquivos as $img){
   echo '<img src=\"imagens/".$img."\">';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como a função `glob()` retorna um array, basta contar o número de índices com a função [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php):

```
$pasta = 'imagens/';
$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

echo "Total de Imagens" . count($arquivos);

foreach($arquivos as $img){
   echo '<img src=\"imagens/".$img."\">';
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando, muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 2):

Você pode incrementar uma variável, assim:

```
<?php 
$pasta = 'imagens/';
$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

$i = 0;

foreach($arquivos as $img){
    echo '<img src=\"imagens/".$img."\">';
    $i++;
}

echo 'Total:', $i;
?>
```

Se quiser obter o resultado antes de exibir as imagens, pode usar um vetor/array

```
<?php 
$pasta = 'imagens/';
$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

$i = 0;
$images = array();

foreach($arquivos as $img){
    $images[] = '<img src=\"imagens/".$img."\">';
    $i++;
}

echo 'Total:', $i;

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $images);
?>
```